# when the e-mails are sent in PrestaShop

Tags: email, prestashop

I am currently working on PrestaShop and I cannot understand when the e-mails are sent. Is there any documentation about this?

Comment: Did you try searching the PrestaShop website for documentation?

Comment: Yes, i've tried. But it does not provide me any information about when they are sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the specific triggers for each email (which you can change and assign as you wish) in your Back Office under Orders > Statuses.

Additionally, you can change any of these templates to fit your own needs in your Back Office either in the /mails directory or in your Back Office under Tools > Translations > Email Template Translations